# Group by based on 4 fields and sum up

Tags: awk, group-by, gawk

Here is how my input looks like:

```
aNumber bNumber startDate   timeZone    duration    currencyType    cost    dicatedAccused  balanceAfter    trafficCase teleServiceCode location    dataVolume  numberOfEvents  fafIndicator    netWorkID   serviceProvideID    serviceClass    nAno    nBno    bNumberZnCode   fileNamedID Destination Operator    unknown3    MainAmount  ReAnalyse   DEDICATEDACCBALBEF  DEDICATEDACCBALAFT  ACCOUNTGROUPID  SERVICEOFFERINGS    SELECTEDCOMMUNITYID BALANCEBEFORE
22677512549 778 2014-07-02 10:16:35.000 NULL    NULL    localCurrency   0,00    2   11.50   0   3   22676020076 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    34  77512549    778 NULL    1131257 OTHER   Short Code  126244088   0.0000  0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11.5000
22675557361 76457227    2014-07-02 10:16:38.000 NULL    NULL    localCurrency   10,00   2   1009.10 0   3   22676613028 NULL    NULL    1   NULL    NULL    35  75557361    76457227    NULL    1131257 Airtel  Airtel  4132206314  10.0000 0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1019.1000
22677521277 778 2014-07-04 10:16:42.000 NULL    NULL    localCurrency   0,00    NULL    0.00    0   4   22676020078 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    34  77521277    778 NULL    1131257 OTHER   Short Code  130071591   0.0000  0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.0000
22676099496 77250331    2014-07-03 10:16:42.000 NULL    NULL    localCurrency   1,00    9   0.50    0   4   22676613028 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    35  76099496    77250331    NULL    1131257 Airtel  Airtel  4132218551  0.0000  0   4.0000  3.0000  NULL    NULL    NULL    0.5000
22667222160 22667262389 2014-07-02 10:16:43.000 NULL    NULL    localCurrency   10,00   1   16070.00    0   4   22676613028 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    35  67222160    67262389    NULL    1131257 Airtel  Airtel  4132222628  10.0000 0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    16080.0000
```

I have to group by date,dicatedAccused,trafficCase and teleserviceCode and then based on the result of this group by i have to sum up duration, cost, balanceAfter, MainAmount, Balancebefore.
It will not be a problem if the sum up where based on only one field but we have to group by using 4 fields

here is the awk script I'm using

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "date Duration Cost BalanceAfter MainAmount DedicatedAccBalBefore DedicatedAccBalAfter BalanceBefore"} NR == 1 {next} function showday() {
    printf "%s\t%d\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\n", date, duration, cost, bAfter, main, dedAccbBefore, dedAccbAfter, bBefore} DedicatedAccUsed != $3 {
   if (date) showday()
   date = $3
   duration = cost = bAfter = main = bBefore = dedAccbBefore = dedAccbAfter = 0}{
   sub(/,/, ".", $8)
   duration += $6
   cost += $8
   bAfter += $10
   main += $(NF-7)
   dedAccbBefore += $(NF-5)
   dedAccbAfter += $(NF-4)
   bBefore += $NF}END {showday()}' test.txt | column -t
```

Here the output i'm looking for

`startDate  dicatedAccused  trafficCase teleServiceCode duration    cost    balanceAfter MainAmount BALANCEBEFORE
02/07/2014  2   0   3   0   10  1020.60 10  1020.60
02/07/2014  1   0   4   0   10  16070.00    10  16080
03/07/2014  9   0   4   0   1   0   0.0000  0,5
04/07/2014  NULL    0   4   0   0   0   0.0000  0`

Comment: Show expected output

Comment: Check it out @Jidder

Comment: they are all relevant

Comment: Which version of gawk ? with gawk 4 you may use real nested arrays, which could solve your problem by using `array['group']['val1']+=` and `array['group']['val2']+=`. with gawk 3 you'll have to do 6 arrays, one for each sum, and one for the 'invariant' part.

Comment: I'm using GNU awk 4.1.1. Can you be more explicit about your idea ? thanks @Tensibai

Comment: @Baodbao I'll write it as an answer, will be more easy. but mainly the idea is to make an array being your group by. i.e: `arr[$1 $2 $3 $4 key1]+=$5` and at end loop over the array and print `key => value` (many values in your case, so you have to make a array of keys minus the 'key1' in my exemple to print the keys then the values.

Comment: okay waiting for your answer but i will try to explore this idea also

Comment: Sorry for the long answer, I had a call. I let you play with my answer as a starting point on formatting etc. I may have overcomplicated it formatting the output, in this case, you can get rid of the printf and sprintf and use spaces as separator, found it easiest to show with a proper formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok output obtained:

```
date         dAccused  TrafficCase  ServiceCode   Duration       Cost BalanceAfter MainAmount BalanceBefore
2014-07-02          1            0            4          0         10      16070         10      16080
2014-07-03          9            0            4          0          1        0.5          0        0.5
2014-07-04       NULL            0            4          0          0          0          0          0
2014-07-02          2            0            3          0         10     1020.6         10     1030.6
```

I've modifed your script a little to just use arrays to store the sums, I add it here with comments:

```
awk '
NR == 1 {next}
{
   sub(/,/, ".", $8)
   key=sprintf("%-10s %10s %12s %12s",$3,$9,$11,$12) # Create the array key for the "group by" style with text formatting for output
   duration[key] += $6 # Do the duration sum with the key
   cost[key] += $8 # the same for cost
   bAfter[key] += $10
   main[key] += $(NF-7)
   dedAccbBefore += $(NF-5) # Unsure of the real use for this one, so not used after but left
   dedAccbAfter += $(NF-4)
   bBefore[key] += $NF
}
END {
    printf "%-10s %10s %12s %12s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\n", "date","dAccused","TrafficCase","ServiceCode","Duration","Cost","BalanceAfter","MainAmount","BalanceBefore" # print the header
    for (i in duration) { # loop over duration array to get the key as index for all the arrays
        printf "%-47s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\n", i,duration[i],cost[i],bAfter[i],main[i],bBefore[i] # print the values (key then actual arrays values
    }
}' test.txt
```

Hope its clear enought, tell me if it needs more details.

Comment: You're welcome. Consider marking the answer as accepted if it solves your question (it helps when looking to question to see which is 'closed')